# Is "соблюдатель" a valid word?

Tags: грамматика, лексикон

..., стать **соблюдателем** существующего порядка и охранником международных правил, или стать ...

or something better to say this in Russian?

Thanks!

Comment: **"стать соблюдателем существующего порядка"** can be translated as **"быть законопослушным"** in the sense of obeying the rules

Comment: Вместо "охранником правил" я бы использовал "защитником правил".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no such word "соблюдатель". You may say "стать блюстителем существующего порядка и охранником международных правил" if you mean one who makes others obey the order ("блюститель порядка" is sometimes used as a synonym for "policeman").

Comment: Thanks, I want to express the meaning that `who obey the order` not `who makes others obey the order`, how to say that?

Comment: You can say "соблюдать существующий порядок"."Принять существующий порядок и стать охранником международных правил" - "Accept the existing order ..." But "Стать охранником" means to make others to obey international rules, did you mean it?

Answer (score 7):

You could also consider using one of the following options:

- стать сторонником
- стать (рьяным) приверженцем
- стать поборником
- стать адептом

Comment: This is useful!